# Rust/Rocket: the trait `serde::ser::Serialize` is not implemented for struct

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm trying to make a simple endpoint using Rocket. My `Cargo.toml` has these dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.2"
rocket_codegen = "0.4.2"
rocket_contrib = "0.4.2"
```

`main.rs` looks like:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use serde::Serialize;

#[get("/org")]
fn getorg() -> Json<Org> {
    Json(Org {
        id: Option::from(25),
        name: "Incredible-Customer".to_string(),
    })
}
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Org {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub name: String,
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![getorg]).launch();
}
```

Compiling results in the errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `serde`
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use serde::Serialize;
  |     ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `serde`

error: cannot determine resolution for the derive macro `Serialize`
  --> src/main.rs:14:10
   |
14 | #[derive(Serialize)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports

error[E0658]: `macro` is experimental
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | #[get("/org")]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #39412 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39412> for more information
  = help: add `#![feature(decl_macro)]` to the crate attributes to enable
  = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Org: serde::ser::Serialize` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:8:16
    |
8   | fn getorg() -> Json<Org> {
    |                ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::ser::Serialize` is not implemented for `Org`
    |
   ::: /Users/shep/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rocket-0.4.5/src/handler.rs:202:20
    |
202 |     pub fn from<T: Responder<'r>>(req: &Request, responder: T) -> Outcome<'r> {
    |                    ------------- required by this bound in `handler::<impl rocket::Outcome<rocket::Response<'r>, rocket::http::Status, rocket::Data>>::from`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Responder<'_>` for `rocket_contrib::json::Json<Org>
```

I'm very confused as to how to look into this error. Is it a dependency issue? Why? I have versioned the `rocket` dependencies to the same one, but apparently this `serde` dependency is unhappy. Googling around claims it's a version mismatch inside one of my dependencies - but how do I go about solving that myself?

Comment: Looks like you have to add `serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"]}` and `serde_json = {version = "1.0"}` inside dependencies section of your `cargo.toml`.

Comment: That worked - thank you. If you make an answer on here, I'll accept it.

Comment: I had this error when I forgot to add `use serde::Serialize`, not a very informative error message.

Answer (score 10):

Add the following lines to your `cargo.toml`

```ini
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"]}
serde_json = {version = "1.0"}
```

to be able to derive from `Serialize` and `Deserialize`